# Destroying element from an external javascript file in angular

Tags: javascript, angular

I am currently adding an element from an external javascript source upon OnInit using this

**HTML**

```
<div id='jsContainer' #jsContainer></div>
```

**TS FILE**

```
let jsDiv = document.getElementById('jsContainer')
script.src = url
script.async = true;
this._renderer2.appendChild(jsDiv,script);
```

Now I want to destroy or remove the element upon ngOnDestroy

I tried to do this

```
if (document.getElementById('jsContainer')) {
  let jsDiv = document.getElementById('jsContainer')
  this._renderer2.removeChild(this._document.body, jsDiv);
}
```

And also this

```
this._renderer2.removeChild(this.elementRef.nativeElement, this.script);
```

But none of them are working. Any idea of how to destroy the element dynamically?

Comment: Maybe this: `jsDiv.parentNode.removeChild(jsDiv);`

Comment: It's not working too

Answer (score 0):

`removeChild()` expects the first parameter to be the parent node of the node you're trying to remove: https://angular.io/api/core/Renderer2#removechild

Since your're appending the element to `jsDiv`:

```
this._renderer2.appendChild(jsDiv,script);
```

you need to remove it from `jsDiv` as well:

```
let jsDiv = document.getElementById('jsContainer')
this._renderer2.removeChild(jsDiv, this.script);
```